display http request response in a Listview
Since I don't know the number of elements I will receive from my HTTP request with Flutter and Dart, I want to automatically generate cards or even containers to display my results. Here is my code that doesn't work:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;




class StfNouveauCompte extends StatefulWidget {
  const StfNouveauCompte({super.key});

  @override
  State<StfNouveauCompte> createState() => _StfNouveauCompteState();
}

class _StfNouveauCompteState extends State<StfNouveauCompte> {
  String msg="";
  var jsonList;
  final _formKey=GlobalKey<FormState> ();
  final controllernom=TextEditingController();
  final controllernconfirmationmotdepasse=TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controllernom.dispose();
    controllernconfirmationmotdepasse.dispose();
  }



Future<void> register(String nom,String prenoms,String mail, telephone,naissance, pseudo, passe1, 
     passe2
    ) async {
      setState(() {
        msg='';
      });
    try {
      
      var url = Uri.parse('https://konamicash.com/register_app');
      var response = await http.post(url, headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },body: {
        "nom_utilisateur":nom,
        "confirmation_du_mot_de_passe":passe2,
      });var codes= response.statusCode;
   

       if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        var data= json.decode(response.body);
      
      });
        print('it works: ${data}');
      
       print(data.length);var count=data.length;
       final List<int> _itemList=List<int>.generate(count,(index)=>index);
                       ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
                  return Card(
                    key:Key('$index'),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text('$data[0]'),
                    ),
                  );

                },);
      

      } else {
        print('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('An error occurred: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Namis.com'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      body:Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    'Register',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 35,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade400),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Nom',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      suffixIcon: Align(
                        widthFactor: 1.0,
                        heightFactor: 1.0,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.person,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),),),
                   
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'password',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                   
                    controller: controllernconfirmationmotdepasse, 
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 50,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                     if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        final nom = controllernom.text;

                        final confirmationmotdepasse =controllernconfirmationmotdepasse.text;

                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());

                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(content: Text('Envoi en cours')));
                            
                            register(nom,prenoms,adressemail,telephone,datedenaissance,pseudo,motdepasse,confirmationmotdepasse);
                        }
                    },
                    child: Text('Créer le compte'),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text("J'ai déjà un compte..."),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text(
                        'Je me connecte',
                        style:
                            TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 245, 11, 11)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                //just bellow the sized box where i want to display my different message result_message
                SizedBox(height:30 ,),
                Text(msg, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

To create the right number of containers or cards to put the results of my HTTP request in.

Hello, Is there any error message?

Use FutureBuilder
you can check the link for more details about FutureBuilder
edit your register function to return data then use FutureBuilder to view list of data inside build
Future  register(String nom,String prenoms,String mail, telephone,naissance, pseudo, passe1, 
     passe2
    ) async {
      setState(() {
        msg='';
      });
    try {
      
      var url = Uri.parse('https://konamicash.com/register_app');
      var response = await http.post(url, headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },body: {
        "nom_utilisateur":nom,
        "confirmation_du_mot_de_passe":passe2,
      });var codes= response.statusCode;
   

       if(response.statusCode == 200) {
     
       return  json.decode(response.body);
       

      } else {
        print('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('An error occurred: $e');
    }
   }


i try to fix you code.
In condition we already know the response will be Map:
{'status':0, 'message': 'success'}
I already commented what i add and the use of the code.
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class StfNouveauCompte extends StatefulWidget {
  const StfNouveauCompte({super.key});

  @override
  State<StfNouveauCompte> createState() => _StfNouveauCompteState();
}

class _StfNouveauCompteState extends State<StfNouveauCompte> {
  String msg = "";
  var jsonList;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final controllernom = TextEditingController();
  final controllernconfirmationmotdepasse = TextEditingController();

  // New variable to save the data from API.
  //
  // [dataFromApi] is nullabel since we need to wait the response from API.
  Map<String, dynamic>? dataFromApi;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controllernom.dispose();
    controllernconfirmationmotdepasse.dispose();
  }

  String getRegisterStatus() {
    // If dataFromApi is null or empty return 'none'
    if (dataFromApi == null || dataFromApi!.isEmpty) {
      return 'None';
    } else {
      // If [dataFromApi] is already assigned by response data then returning
      // the status from response data.
      return '${dataFromApi?['message']}';
    }
  }

  Future<void> register(String nom, String prenoms, String mail, telephone,
      naissance, pseudo, passe1, passe2) async {
    setState(() {
      msg = '';
    });
    try {
      var url = Uri.parse('https://konamicash.com/register_app');
      var response = await http.post(url, headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }, body: {
        "nom_utilisateur": nom,
        "confirmation_du_mot_de_passe": passe2,
      });

      var codes = response.statusCode;

      if (codes == 200) {
        // Show response in console log
        print('[INFO] your response:\n$dataFromApi');

        // assign response data to [dataFromApi]
        dataFromApi = json.decode(response.body);

        // Rebuild state to inform state that [dataFromApi] is changed it's value
        setState(() {});
      } else {
        print('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('An error occurred: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Namis.com'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    'Register',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 35,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade400),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Nom',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      suffixIcon: Align(
                        widthFactor: 1.0,
                        heightFactor: 1.0,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.person,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'password',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    controller: controllernconfirmationmotdepasse,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 50,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        final nom = controllernom.text;

                        final confirmationmotdepasse =
                            controllernconfirmationmotdepasse.text;

                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());

                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(content: Text('Envoi en cours')));

                        register(
                            nom,
                            prenoms,
                            adressemail,
                            telephone,
                            datedenaissance,
                            pseudo,
                            motdepasse,
                            confirmationmotdepasse);
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text('Créer le compte'),
                  ),
                ),

                // New widget to show your response data
                Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Text('Register status = ${getRegisterStatus()}'),
                  ),
                ),

                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text("J'ai déjà un compte..."),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text(
                        'Je me connecte',
                        style:
                            TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 245, 11, 11)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                //just bellow the sized box where i want to display my different message result_message
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Text(
                  msg,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is just the basic example to use the data for the widget. I suggest you to learn FutureBuilder for data fetching from API.
Hope it helps! If you have any question please just ask:) thanks.

ok i just tried your code and i have this error /flutter ( 4920): An error occurred: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List'

So that mean the response.body that assigned to dataFromApi is not a List ([value, value ,value]) but a 'Map' ({key1: value, key2: value}), that pretty usual for API response.

Maybe we need to know what is your API response look like, and then we can treat the response data nicely.

Exactly we have à map ({"status":0, "message":"succes when registering"})

Okey, i'll edit my code to adjust to your response

i just edited my code, it will show the response as text. I'll wait for your feedback.

100000000k tank you you save my encore life

wow ur welcome, glad i can help! if you don't mind, please mark my answer as accepted. thanks:)

D'ont worry about that i Will do it

Well now i have this error: _typeError(type 'List la not à subtype of 'map<string,dynamic> of 'function result')

I have it at Line 22, map<string,dynamic>? dataFromApi;

That mean you assigned a List type value to dataFromApi that already have Map type. You can create new variable List dataList = [] to assign List type value

by the way, this what the php code of the api looks like       $errors=array();
$errors['status']=1;
$errors['message']="mail sent...";
echo json_encode($errors);

ah it's very strange because i don't see where i have assigned a list type value to dataFrom api??do you see something??

And what if i use a loop foreach for each items of datafromapi?

just to confirm, is the code that i just edit is work before?

when you got this error error: _typeError(type 'List<dynamic> la not à subtype of 'map<string,dynamic> of 'function result')? i mean, what you did before get this error?

Yes my code and the http request worked before but its only the part of the listview that doesnt work

what do you want to show in ListView? since the response is only a message that the process is success ( {"status": 0, "message": "success"} ), or maybe you fetch another API request?

suppose we just have this simple code(maybe start from the beggining is a good thing),the url for the http request is https://konamicash.com/register_app,

well sure i want to display the message that the process is a success but the api may send other information that i would like to display too, that the reason why i don't know how many items in my list view i will need, so i want to generate them automatically depending on the number of items in my api response

Ohh i see what you try to achieve, you want to make your function is dynamically adapt to your response data. In my experience, it's not good approach to fetch data blindly. For a good stability, consistency, and other important reason, you need to define API as it is functionality. Such as API konamicash.com/register_app for register user, $konamiUrl/login for user login, $konamiUrl/users for getting list users data, and other.

I do not recommend you use one API for all purposes

ok so i will do so, but how can i dynamically adapt my function to my response,, i edited my first code to a basic one with only a simple container that display"Register" how do i make the http request and dinamically generate the listview or the container ?

For dynamic function to handle random API response type, i already create an example code based on your case. Check it here Github Gist

I Will let you know tank you very much again for your help

hi, i hope you are doing well, well in the Github Gist there is no error,but it doesn't work because nothing is displayed

no error in screen too?

Hi i hope you are doing well and sorry for replying so late, well it works well now i found a solution and thank you again... but i have another issue i can't pass variables form a page to another with simple code and i don't know where i am wrong? can you check it please, it is going to be veeeeeery helpful, thank you

sure, where can i check you code?

thank you very much https://pastebin.com/sndGagCj, you can see my code just right here,

i see the problem, i suggest you to create new question in stackoverflow then mention me so i can post my answer there

i don't know why but i still have a problem when i want to post on stackoverflow,

Ok i just changed you Gaming class this should be fine: PasteBin

ok thanks i will let you know in 10 minutes

ok in VScode, i don't have the error anymore controlleradressemail is not defined and i can run the app , but mail is not displayed in the gamepage

you need to add onChanged: (_) => setState(() {}), to your TextField

Ok and what if i want To put the value of the controlleradressemail in a variàble like mail To use it after?

set your variable like String email = controlleradressemail.text; in your function then use it.

I suggest you to explore in TextFormField doc for more understanding about TextFormField. I guess this is my last answer in this question, it'll be endless discussion because this already too far from the original question. Glad to help, thanks.

Yes i really appreciate your Help...tank you very much for jour help
